# how to deselect the previous selected image when another image is selected using tap gesture in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

i have a scroll view which contain the many image. i am select the using the tap gesture.
[image]

select image are set like that. this part is done successfully.![image]

But my problem is it's give me multiple selection when i tap another.i want to remove previous selection. [image]

i want some thing like that, when i am select next image then previous one are deselect.
[image]

sorry, for bad explanation.

Thanks in advance.

code of create scroll view

```
//below code are for create scroll view 



-(void)viewDidLoad{   
    scrollView.delegate = self;
 scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
 int scrollWidth = 70;
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,50);

    int xOffset = 0;

 for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
 {

  img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [img setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  img.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);
  img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 5, 60, 40);

        //below line add here
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];

        img.tag = 303 + index;

      //  [img.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
       // [img.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];

        [Scrollimages insertObject:img atIndex:index];

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,50);
        [scrollView addSubview:[Scrollimages objectAtIndex:index]];

       //xOffset += 170;

        xOffset += 70;
 }


    for (UIImageView *scrollimage in Scrollimages) {

           UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizerInScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewsingleTappedInScrollMethod:)];

        singleTapRecognizerInScroll.delegate = self;

        singleTapRecognizerInScroll.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTapRecognizerInScroll.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


        [scrollimage  addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecognizerInScroll];

        }     
  }  
 -(void)scrollViewsingleTappedInScrollMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

       scrollimageview = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

      //we select the image using tag.(contain many images)
    if ([scrollimageview tag] == 303) {

        selectLimitSet = 3;

        }

        }
```

Comment: sure this isn't a collectionview, and could you provide some code how you are setting the status to selected?

Comment: ya, it's a scroll view not a collection view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        int scrollWidth = 70;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,50);

        int xOffset = 0;

        for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
        {

            img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [img setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            img.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);
            img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 5, 60, 40);

            //below line add here
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];

            img.tag = 303 + index;

            //add below code is here


//take A UIView * displayView make it global (create Instance).

            displayView = img;
            img.alpha = 1.0;


            [Scrollimages insertObject:img atIndex:index];

            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,50);
            [scrollView addSubview:[Scrollimages objectAtIndex:index]];

            //xOffset += 170;

            xOffset += 70;


        }

-(void)scrollViewsingleTappedInScrollMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    //selectedImageInScrollView it's a integer value

    selectedImageInScrollView = recognizer.view.tag;

// set your instance displayView Alpha & set tag them. 

//displayView is first deselect your first view then select next image

    displayView.alpha = 1.0;
    displayView =recognizer.view;

    recognizer.view.alpha = 0.5;


    if (selectedImageInScrollView == 303) {

        selectLimitSet = 3;
        NSLog(@"selectLimitSet : %i",selectLimitSet);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are selecting an image save its reference to selected image. When next is selected un select the current imageview and select new where you got tap gesture. 
1. Create a property to remember current selected image view tag `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentTag;`

```
-(void)onTapGesture(id)sender{
    if(self.currentTag == sender.tag){
     //tap on previously selected image
     //you can deselect same image or any thing else you want to do.
     return;
    }
    UIImageView *prevImageView = [self.view viewWithTag:self.currentTag];
    //deselect prevImageView, if you want to change image do it now
    UIImageView *selectedImageView = (UIImageView*)sender; 
    self.currentTag = selectedImageView.tag;
   //select selectedImageView now, change image now.
}
```

Comment: i have a many images and this images are touch using TAG.your way into manages that are difficult.

Comment: Yup this is an approach which can follow to do this work. We can same current and previous tag to select and deselect Image View.
You can use UICollectioView for this purpose or UITableView, now It depends upon your approach and need.:)

Comment: But how to deselect previous tag, is my question?i am find the current tag and set it's image view alpha.

Comment: When you select new image, at that time you have current tag pointing to previous selected tag. So first deselect previous selected Image (which is current tag), now select the sender (where you got touch) after selecting new, change the value of currentTag to sender.tag(now this will be pointing to new, and when you will touch some other at that time it will be used to deselect previous image). Hope you got my point, if not as for the explanation, I will try to explain more.

Comment: +1 , if u have demo code, then please sent me, thanks a lot.Post here only select and deselect logic.

Comment: my question is how to deselect previous image? any idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use a UICollectionView. It will do all the work for you.

Comment: A helpful answer is a one with some source code. Amon please provide some source code if possible.

Comment: I disagree, this is a very useful answer :)